# Extended soft-thresholding problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I know the solution to the following problem :
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} (y-x)^{2} + \lambda|x|
\end{equation} 
is the soft thresholding function. I would like th know the solution of the following extended problem:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} (y-x)^{2} + \lambda_{1}|x| +\lambda_{2}|x|
\end{equation}

Comment: It is also the soft-thresholding function but now with parameter $\lambda$ instead of $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: because $\lambda_1|x| + \lambda_2|x|= (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)|x|$.